# Why isn't allowed design mode usage with a template?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am adding a button by dragging it from the toolbox in design mode but I can't see it as in the picture. It just shows me my template work as in the picture. What can I do for this?

[image]

Comment: Can you check the source code, is the button there?

Comment: @Tasos K. It appears there but designing is difficult in source mode. So that I asked this question